# Como obter o nome do arquivo para ser aberto com meu programa ao clicar neste arquivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argumento

Criei um reprodutor de música na linguagem Python e eu gostaria de saber como posso reproduzir uma música com meu programa ao clicar no arquivo. Por exemplo quando eu abro uma música agora, ela é reproduzida automaticamente no Windows Media Player.

Me disseram que posso obter o caminho de onde o script é chamado com `sys.argv` dessa forma:

```
import sys
import os

for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

Mas eu gostaria de obter também o caminho do arquivo que é aberto com o meu programa. Quando eu executo o meu código, a única coisa que obtenho da lista é o caminho do script:

```
["C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Nova pasta\script.py"]
```

Como posso fazer para reproduzir músicas com meu programa assim como no WMP?

Comment: Eu sinceramente não entendi a sua pergunta. Se a sua dúvida é sobre como abrir uma música com o seu reprodutor sempre, você vai ter que primeiramente gerar um executável do seu código. Depois disso clique em **Abrir com > Escolher programa padrão** e escolha o seu programa. Após isso, sempre que você for abrir uma música, o seu programa será executado e o caminho absoluto dessa música será passada no `sys.argv`.

Comment: Está difícil de perguntar porque você não tem uma ideia clara do que precisa.Veja essa lib:  https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Sim disso tudo eu sei, mas como o me programa mesmo compilado vai reconhecer o arquivo, como que ele vai ter o caminho do arquivo se ele não pode pois não sei como...dei uma olhada nesse site mas não intendi o propósito.

Comment: Phoenix como eu disse antes, ao abrir uma música com um programa o diretório da música é passado no `sys.argv`. A biblioteca `argparse` que o Augusto mencionou é um parser para melhorar a forma que se coloca e recebe os dados inseridos na linha de comando na execução do programa.

Comment: Phoenix, aqui está um exemplo de como você obtém o arquivo de música para reproduzir no seu programa. https://repl.it/repls/SingleMuffledCell Apenas gere um executável desse código e siga os passos que eu mostrei no meu primeiro comentário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom como agora a pergunta ficou um pouco mais clara e especifica, agora já da para responder.

Como eu disse nos comentários, para reproduzir um arquivo de música ou qualquer outro arquivo no Windows utilizando o seu programa, primeiro você terá que gerar um executável do código.

Depois de gerado o executável, você precisará configurar o seu programa como padrão para que possa sempre ser executado ao reproduzir o tipo de arquivo desejado.

Para fazer isso, basta seguir as etapas abaixo:

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse no arquivo desejado.
- Clique em "Abrir com" > "Escolher programa padrão..." > "Procurar...".
- Selecione o executável do seu programa.
- Deixe a caixa "Sempre usar o programa selecionado para abrir este tipo de arquivo" marcada.
- Clique em "OK" para realizar as alterações.

---

*"Ok, configurei tudo como mandou. Mas como eu vou fazer meu programa obter este arquivo ?"*

Quando você clica duas vezes no arquivo para ser aberto, o Windows executa internamente um programa definido como padrão para reproduzir o arquivo.

Ao executar o programa, o Windows passa na linha de comando digamos assim (não sei ao certo como funciona isso internamente), o caminho absoluto do arquivo clicado pelo usuário.

Você pode obter o caminho do arquivo na linguagem Python através da lista `sys.argv`. Essa lista armazena todos os dados inseridos ao executar o programa na linha de comando.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import sys

class YourPlayer(object):
    """
    Simulação do seu player que vai reproduzir a música.
    """
    def __init__(self, sound):
        self.__sound = sound

    def run(self):
        print("Playing " + self.__sound)

# Recebe o caminho absoluto do arquivo de música.
sound_filename = sys.argv[1] 
player = YourPlayer(sound_filename)

# Executa o seu player.
player.run() 
input()      # Esse input é só para não terminar o programa.
```

> Veja funcionado online: https://repl.it/repls/SingleMuffledCell

*"Mas quando eu executo o programa, eu obtenho na lista apenas o caminho do script executado."*

Se isso está acontecendo é por dois motivos. O primeiro motivo, é que você parece não ter entendido a parte onde eu falo que você precisa gerar um executável do seu código. O que precisa estar na lista em primeiro lugar não é o caminho do script e sim do executável.

O segundo motivo, é porque você está abrindo o seu programa sozinho. O que você deveria fazer é clicar duas vezes no arquivo a ser reproduzido para abrir o arquivo com o seu programa.

Você também pode executar diretamente o seu programa com um nome de arquivo na linha de comando. Exemplo:

```
> MyPlayer "minha_musica.mp3"
```

---

Apenas para complementar, a respeito do `argparse` que o Augusto mencionou nos comentários, essa é uma biblioteca com o objetivo de parser os dados inseridos na linha de comando.

Como essa não é uma pergunta sobre `argparse` não vou explicar aqui como ela funciona, mas você pode aprender facilmente o básico dessa biblioteca [neste site](https://cadernodelaboratorio.com.br/2017/06/05/python-3-processando-argumentos-da-linha-de-comando/) (foi onde eu aprendi).

Abaixo está um exemplo de como essa biblioteca funciona:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description = "Um programa de exemplo")
parser.add_argument("--file", help = "Arquivo a ser reproduzido", required = True)
parser.add_argument("--vol", help = "Volume inicial do áudio", type = int, default = 60)

arguments = parser.parse_args()
print("Reproduzindo", arguments.file, "no volume", str(arguments.vol) + "%")
```

Executando o código:

```
> script.py --file="minha_musica.mp3"
Reproduzindo minha_musica.mp3 no volume 60%

> script.py --file="minha_musica.mp3" --vol=97
Reproduzindo minha_musica.mp3 no volume 97%

> script.py
usage: script.py [-h] --file FILE [--vol VOL]
script.py: error: the following arguments are required: --file
```

Como você pode ver, através do `argparse` podemos inserir os argumentos de uma forma mais elegante, definir parâmetros como obrigatórios, definir o tipo do valor de cada parâmetro, definir um valor padrão para o parâmetro, obter uma mensagem de ajuda, entre outras coisas mais.

Espero ter lhe ajudado :)